# Why FirstOrDefault get this exception? Sequence contains no matching element exception

Tags: c#, linq

I hope you can help me to my code after I change the data type of the following I get this exception "Sequence contains no matching element exception. ". And I am sure this because of FirstOrDefault() Extension.

```
LandId - long
ShowMapPoint - string
Development - string
Location - string
MapPointX - string
MapPointY - string
AreaSize - from decimal? into long?
Premium - from decimal? into long?
TransactionPrice - from decimal? into long?
```

This is my code:

```
var result = _context.DwPropertyMasters.Where(x => x.ShowMapPoint == "Y")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.LandId,
                    a = x.Development == null || x.Development == "" ? x.Location : x.Development,
                    x.MapPointX,
                    x.MapPointY,
                    AreaSize = x.AreaSize ?? 0,
                    Premium = x.Premium ?? 0,
                    b = (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize) ?? 0,
                    c =
                    _context.DwPropertyDetails.Where(
                            z => (z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null) && z.LandId == x.LandId)
                        .GroupBy(z => z.LandId)
                        .Select(g =>
                            (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice)) /
                            (g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize)) ?? 0)
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
                    d =
                    ((x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2) == 0
                        ? 0
                        : (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2)) ??
                    0,
                    x.LandType,
                    e =
                    _context.DwPropertyDetails.Where(
                            y => (y.TransactionPrice > 0 || y.TransactionPrice != null) && y.LandId == x.LandId)
                        .Select(y => new
                        {
                            a = 1
                        }).Count()
                });
```

Comment: *And I am sure this because of FirstOrDefault() Extension* - How/why are you sure?

Comment: Because when I remove the .FirstOrDefault() of c anonymous datatype change the datatype into of IQueryable<long>. My question is why this happening? Any idea bro?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the same exception. Sequence contains no matching element exception.

Comment: I wonder how this statement behaves: b = (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize) ?? 0. If x.Premium == 0 then you'll get 'null * 100000000 etc.'. And if x.AreaSize == 0 then you'll get '? * 100000000 / null'. Perhaps you should test x.Premium and x.AreaSize first: b = (x.Premium == 0 || x.AreaSize == 0) ? 0 : (x.Premium * 100000000 / x.AreaSize). And you don't even have to test x.Premium to get 0: b = (x.AreaSize == 0) ? 0 : (x.Premium * 100000000 / x.AreaSize)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the sum of the `Premium` and `TransactionPrice`

If you grouping doesn't contain an item with a value, then it will try to sum null values. That can't work.

I would change it as follows:

```
(g.All(p => p.TransactionPrice == null) ? null : g.Where(p => p.TransactionPrice != null).Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice))
```

and

```
(g.All(p => p.ActualSize == null) ? null : g.Where(p => p.ActualSize != null).Sum(p => p.ActualSize)))
```

First check if everything is null, then it is null, else sum the values.

But you need to edit your code further, your current code would enable situations like `123 / null` or `null / 123`. Which would also be a exception.

Comment: If you add the (g.All ... ) you will get the red squiggly error. right?

Comment: @StephenShuane no? it shouldn't. All is just a linq method to check if all items pass the lambda. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx and https://www.dotnetperls.com/all

Comment: the same exception. Sequence contains no matching element exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you are doing. It is way too complex with all these inline if's. And on line 13 you have:

```
z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null.
```

You might as well remove z.TransactionPrice > 0, because the second part allows all values (not null), including everything smaller than 0.

The 'Sequence contains no matching element'  exception is typically something I'd expect when you use .First(). Not .FirstOrDefault().

Based on your code and what I think you want to achieve I have rewritten the query:

```
var result = _context.DwPropertyMasters.Where(x => x.ShowMapPoint == "Y")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.LandId,
                    a = x.Development == null || x.Development == "" ? x.Location : x.Development,
                    x.MapPointX,
                    x.MapPointY,
                    AreaSize = x.AreaSize ?? 0,
                    Premium = x.Premium ?? 0,
                    b = (x.AreaSize == 0) ? 0 : (x.Premium * 100000000 / x.AreaSize ?? 0),
                    c = _context.DwPropertyDetails.Where(z => z.TransactionPrice > 0 && z.LandId == x.LandId)
                        .GroupBy(z => z.LandId)
                        .Select(g => g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? 0 : (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) / g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) ?? 0)
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
                    d = (x.AreaSize2 == 0) ? 0 : (x.Premium * 100000000 / x.AreaSize2 ?? 0),
                    x.LandType,
                    e = _context.DwPropertyDetails.Count(y => y.TransactionPrice > 0 && y.LandId == x.LandId)
                });
```

I do not know if this works as you intended (and works at all since I didn't test this), but it is shorter and I hope more readable.

Keep in mind that this query is executed in sql server, so there is no need to check for null values. The only thing that must be prevented is to divide by zero. If we consider the next line:

```
b = (x.AreaSize == 0) ? 0 : (x.Premium * 100000000 / x.AreaSize ?? 0)
```

If:

- x.AreaSize is null then (x.Premium * 100000000 / null ?? 0) => null ?? 0 => 0.
- x.AreaSize = 0 then the result = 0.
- x.Premium is null then the result is null / value ?? 0 => null ?? 0 => 0.
- x.Premium = 0 then the result = 0.